# How to turn an identifier into a string

Tags: javascript, reflection

Consider the following code:

```js
class C {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop) {
    return prop;
  }
});

const str = proxy.doSomething;

console.log(str);

const c = new C();
c[str]();
```

I have been able to turn the identifier `doSomething` into the string `"doSomething"`.

This happens to be useful in situations when dealing with minified code, where I don't know in advance what the identifier `doSomething` will be minified as.

Is there a way to obtain this string without using a Proxy?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it without proxy. Usually minifiers don't minify object properties though...

Comment: @code I enable object property minification for more compact code

Comment: Okay. As I said, I don't think there's a way to do it besides proxy... what's wrong with proxy?

Comment: @code Proxy works, but it just seems a little inelegant. I'm hoping someone else might know of another way to do this